# Вытягивать данные погоды WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть приложение небольшое на WPF. Хочу чтобы оно показывало текущую температуру на улице. Нашел сайт https://openweathermap.org, там же API ключ бесплатный. Но не нашел нигде информации как этот ключ использовать чтобы он показывал температуру

Comment: Этот api-ключ используется каждый раз при запросе к их api. У них на сайте есть документация по api: https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: Идете в документацию, видите что надо на сайт отправить POST/GET запрос с нужными данными, пишете вон, сверху на SO в поиске `[c#] POST` и видите уйму ответов на эту тему... А сейчас я лично, по увиденному, делаю вывод, что вы даже не пытались решить это самостоятельно, а вместо решения, пошли спрашивать "у прохожих" как это написать, авось напишут за вас...